# HTML Drop down list from Value

Tags: jquery, html, drop-down-menu

*The real question here was for what I answered below, I think I figured out how to fix the rest. I will come back later if I need help, so some details will be removed from this original post.

I will expose my 2 questions at the same time.

The first and real reason I am here, I am building an app that creates a form depending on which fields are selected.

I have a count for each field selected. I want to populate a drop down list with the number of box selected. So if I have 5, then in the list I need 1-2-3-4-5.

```
var showcounter = 5
```

The variable is only a number of checked box!

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you please add some code ?

Comment: Wait am Changing my question I found the first information I needed of course right after I posted the my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*The first question I had here was, how to setup a drop box depending on a number value, here is the proper code I found to do it:

To populate a drop down list depending on a variable value (number):

**jQuery Script**

```
$(function(){
    var $select = $(".dropdown_test");
    var showcounter = 5
    for (i=0;i<=showcounter;i++){
        $select.append($('<option></option>').val(i).html(i))
    }
});
```

**HTML Form field**

```
<select class="dropdown_test"></select>
<select class="dropdown_test"></select>
<select class="dropdown_test"></select>
```

Here is how to do it,

$select in the jQuery is set to the "class" you have set for your "select" drop down list

the variable showcounter will change depending on other scripts but basically here set to 5 as an example.

the "for" line say how many time to redo the action, in my case from 0 to 5 (showcounter variable) and then it fills the options for each drop down list

You can see the result in JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/preYN/282/)